# Android: ListView onScrollListener doesn't stop listening

Tags: android, android-listview

I've implemented ListView in my application and working on onScrollListener. The ListView is working fine and in the onScroll() method of the onScrollListener, i'm trying to show a progressbar when the user has scrolled to the bottom.

The problem is that the listener doesn't stop listening and there are multiple progressbar loading on the screen if the user is trying to scroll even more. I don't have any idea how to solve this. 
I want the onScrollListener to stop listening when the progressbar shows.

Please help

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() == list.getAdapter().getCount() - 
                        && list.getChildAt(list.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= list.getHeight()) {
                ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
                pb.setLayoutParams(pbParams);
                linearLayout.addView(pb);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just check to see if there is already a progress bar and not add another?

Comment: I want to load data from a website in the background. So, if progressbars keep on adding, it also means that there will be multiple requests for the website

Comment: @LalithMohan I would add a Progress dialog while loading, which will blocks the UI from other scroll events. User must wait until download comlete or crash happens, or no connection...

Comment: @matheszabi That's a good alternative if this doesn't work for me